A kind of "boundary degree $=1$" for each continous function $f:D^2\rightarrow D^2$

I think my question is not totally precise, because I am trying to make my intuition more rigorous:
Take a continous function $f:D^2\rightarrow D^2$ where $D^2$ means the two-dimensional disk. I am interested in the behaviour of $f$ on the boundary $\partial D^2=S^1$ which I have drawn as a red circle. I think of $S^1$ in terms of the boundary of $D^2$, hence I prefer to use the notation $\partial D^2$.
(Let me make a bold simplifying assumption for now: $f(x)\neq x$ on $\partial D^2)$
If we restrict $f$ to $\partial D^2$, it has a codomain which is a closed curve that I call $f(\partial D^2)$. I have drawn $f(\partial D^2)$ in blue colour. Each $x\in \partial D^2$ has an image $f(x)\in f(\partial D^2)$. Each pair $(x,f(x))$ defines a vector. So we can say $f$ defines a vector field on $\partial D^2$. I have drawn five example vectors of this vector field in the diagram. (The simplifying assumption $f(x)\neq x$ on $\partial D^2$ means we don’t have to think about null vectors here.)
Now let's travel once around the circle or boundary $\partial D^2$. If you move along the boundary, e.g. starting in $x_1$, going clockwise along $\partial D^2$, until you are finally arriving back home at $x_1$: I believe that, at the end of this journey, the corresponding vector $(x,f(x))$ has turned as well exactly once; in other words, I believe that this vector has made exactly one rotation.

Is this correct, and which theorem does it correspond to?

A few remarks, hopefully helpful and not distracting:
(1) This vector turning around once feels to me almost like "degree $1$" or "winding number $1$", but I know that these invariants of $f$ are defined differently. So I do not know how to call it (maybe "rotation induced by $f$ on $\partial D^2$").
(2) This vector turning around once remains true even in special cases when $f$ is a constant function. In that case, it is even trivial that $(x,f(x))=(x,x_0)$ makes exactly one rotation.
(3) This is similar to the "Turning Tangent Theorem" from Heinz Hopf (for example Continuity of homotopy in proof of Hopf's Umlaufsatz). But obviously it is not the same, because I am not looking at tangents to $\partial D^2$, and the movement of my "turning vector" is determined by a function $f$.
(4) Why I believe the vector turns exactly once: It seems intuitively clear. And I think it is used in the proofs of Brouwer's fixed point theorem through Sperner's lemma. See for example Michael Henle: „A Combinatorial Introduction to Topology“; and similarly in Günter Ziegler and Martin Aigner: „Proofs from THE BOOK“.

You are correct, the vector you described will always make one rotation as $x$ goes around the circle. Furthermore, the rotation of the vector goes the same direction as the rotation of $x$, so the winding number/degree of the path of this vector is $+1$.
Let $T_f(x)$ be the unit vector pointing in the direction from $x$ to $f(x)$. That is,
$$
T_f(x)=\frac{f(x)-x}{\|f(x)-x\|}.
$$
Note that $T_f:\partial D^2\to \partial D^2$. This means that we can speak of the degree of $T_f$, in the usual sense, which is equivalent to the winding number of $T_f$ around the origin. In order to answer your question, we must prove that $\deg T_f=1$.
Now, let $g(x):\partial D^2\to D^2$ be constant map where $g(x)=\vec 0$ for all $x\in \partial D^2$. The functions $f$ and $g$ are homotopy equivalent, via the homotopy
$$
H(x,t)=(1-t)f(x).
$$
Now, define $T_g:\partial D^2\to \partial D^2$ analogously to $T_f$.
$$
T_g(x)=\frac{g(x)-x}{\|g(x)-x\|}=\frac{-x}{\|-x\|}=-x. 
$$ We can use $H$ to construct a homotopy equivalence between $T_f$ and $T_g$. The homotopy is $\tilde H$, defined by
$$
\tilde H(x,t)= \frac{H(x,t)-x}{\|H(x,t)-x\|}.
$$
Since $T_f$ and $T_g$ are both maps from the circle to itself, they both have a degree. Since the two maps are homotopic, it is true that $\deg T_f=\deg T_g$. Finally, you can check that $\deg T_g=+1$ (in general, the map $\eta:S_n\to S_n$ defined by $\eta(x)=-x$ has degree $(-1)^n$). We conclude that $\deg T_f=+1$, as claimed.

Mike thanks a lot for a great answer. Please let me ask quick clarifying questions: (1) you call $T_f$ a tangent vector; I did not quite understand: tangent to what? (2) Is division by $|..|$ actually required? If we could do without this division, maybe I could remove my simplifying assumption $f(x)\neq x$. It is funny, in a sense, that my question needs to exclude the identity $\mbox{id}:\partial D^2\rightarrow\partial D^2$. Normally, one would assume that the identity is the "trivial" part for degree-related questions, but here it is actually the hard part.

(1) “Tangent” was the wrong word, I’ve edited to fix (2) The assumption $f(x)\neq x$ is essential for this problem, as far as I can tell. For winding number around a point $p$ to be well defined, the path must not pass through $p$, so $f(x)-x$ must never be zero to talk about winding around zero.

It is true, but the reason is different from the one in Sperner's lemma (*).
The vector from $x$ to $f(x)$ goes from circle $S^1$ to $D^2$. Hence this vector, at a point $x$ with polar coordinates $(1, \theta)$, assuming it is never zero-length, has an angle comprised in $(\theta + \frac \pi 2, \theta + \frac {3\pi} 2)$.
So let's represent this angle in a continuous manner in $\mathbb R$, not modulo $2 \pi$. We have a continuous function $g$ from $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ to $(\frac \pi 2, \frac {7 \pi} 2)$.
As $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2 \pi$ are the same point, we must have $g(2 \pi) = g(0) [2 \pi]$. As $g(0) \in (\frac \pi 2, \frac {3 \pi} 2)$, and $g(2 \pi) \in (\frac {5 \pi} 2, \frac {7 \pi} 2)$, the only possibility is $g(2 \pi) = g(0) + 2 \pi$. This means one turn is made.
(*) Well, in Sperner's lemma, the "$1$ turn" result actually comes from Sperner conditions on triangle edges ; if these conditions are lifted, one can get any number of turns, hence the number of complete triangles positively oriented minus the number of complete triangles negatively oriented can be any number, including $0$. But then one could argue that Sperner conditions on the triangle edges are similar to the implicit conditions on the vector angle in your problem...

Jean-Armand, thanks a lot! I think this is a very good geometric answer! If my understanding is correct, your answer assumes a geometric circle embedded in the plane (as opposed to a topological "rubber sheet" circle $S^1$, is that correct? (Maybe I have misunderstood.)

@OLEG Yes, I assume a real circle in the plane, rather than a topological circle. Actually it would be tricky to define a "number of rotations" of a vector in a more general setting than the plane. For example in $\mathbb R ^ 3$, the topological circle could make $2$ loops (similar to the blue line in your drawing, but without self-intersection) or more, and still be the boundary of a $2$ dimensional manifold.

@OLEG An interesting follow-up is whether this "one turn" property extends to higher dimensions. For example, in $\mathbb R ^ 3$ using the sphere $S^2$ as boundary to a ball, does the vector always span a full $4 \pi$ solid angle ? Note that if the vector is always perpendicular to the tangent plane, the result is probably equivalent to Gauss-Bonnet theorem, i.e. the total curvature is $2 \pi$ times the Euler characteristic of the surface. But here the vector is allowed to take its direction in a half-space around the perpendicular.

Jean-Armand I agree with you, we are close to the world of Gauss-Bonnet here. I am not sure how your elegant proof translates into higher dimensions. But I am confident that the overall degree $1$ statement generalizes to higher dimensions. I can see this from Mike Earnest‘s answer which is completely independent of dimension. One could say that „rotation$=1$“ generalizes to „degree$=1$“.
